# ¿por qué la función FECHANUMERO arroja #¡VALOR!?

Tags: excel

Estoy probando la función fecha numero pero por alguna razón esta no funciona como se esperaba ni con el ejemplo mas simple, quizás me puedan ayudar en saber que estoy haciendo mal, les dejo imágenes de referencias.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las fechas en Excel son números enteros. La primera fecha que Excel reconoce es el número 1, que equivale a 1 de enero de 1900, el 2 es 2 de enero de 1900 y así sucesivamente. Concretamente, hoy 27/05/2022 es 44708.

Por otro lado, la función FECHANUMERO transforma **un texto** en una valor numérico. El argumento que tú estás pasando es un número, no un texto y por lo tanto da error de tipo #VALOR

El error de tipo #VALOR básicamente significa, como decimos en España, que estás mezclando churras con merinas. Normalmente suele ser que donde Excel espera un número se pone un texto, o viceversa (que sería tu caso). Fíjate en la imagen inferior:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La fórmula de la columna B es `FECHANUMERO(A1)` y arrastrando. En el primer caso da error porque la fecha está metida como número, pero en el segundo he forzado que sea como texto y sí funciona, exactamente la misma fórmula.

La manera más rápida de saber si Excel está leyendo un dato como número o texto es simple: Excel por defecto alinea los datos numéricos a la derecha de la celda y a la izquierda los textos. En mi imagen verás que la fecha de A1 está a la derecha (está siendo reconocida como número) pero en A2 está siendo reconocida como texto (y por eso se alinea a la izquierda y la fórmula funciona)

Prueba a meter tus fechas precedidas de una comilla simple, `'` y verás que FECHANUMERO funciona

Comment: +1 por `mezclar churras con merinas`; en colombia es `mezclar peras con manzanas` :)

Comment: Viva Colombia!!

Comment: Tu explicación y también tu ejemplo me fue de mucha ayuda, gracias.